# What will be the correct IP address if I want to establish socket connection between pc and Android emulator?

Tags: android, sockets

I am trying to use pc as server and Android emulator as client.I want to send a message from server to client.Here's the code:
server:

```
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;
    public class SimpleServer {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws IOException
        {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(30000);
            while(true) {
                Socket s = ss.accept();
                OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
                os.write("Hello World!\n".getBytes("utf-8"));
                os.close();
                s.close();
             }
        }
    }
```

Client:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        EditText text;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.messg);

           new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        // What ip address should be chosen here?
                        Socket socket = new Socket("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",30000); 
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                        String line = br.readLine();
                        text.setText(line);
                        br.close();
                        socket.close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }.start();

        }
    }
```

I have test the code of server and client on the same computer using localhost:127.0.0.1 and it works.However, I can't figure out if the client is the emulator launched by genymotion on the same computer, what will be the correct IP address for the client socket to connect?

I am using wifi and I have tried IP address of wlan0 (found by ifconfig),127.0.0.1, and the public IP address of my computer (found by Google), but the client emulator doesn't display the message from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to refer to the computer which is running the Android simulator, use the IP address **10.0.2.2** instead. You can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)

Comment: 10.0.2.2 for default AVD and 10.0.3.2 for genymotion.problem solved,thx!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the local area network IP address of the computer? In your ifconfig you must get something line

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ...
    inet 192.168.43.238
```

So use 192.168.43.238

Comment: Since I do not use wired net connection,I can't find ip address of eth0 in my ifconfig.

Comment: On wifi you should still have `en0`. `127.0.0.1` will be `lo0`, you should have another entry for your wifi, with your ip on your lan, most likely starting with 192.168.*.*